# How can I convert a 2D image to 3D on Android?

Tags: android, image, 3d

I need to display a 2D image as a 3D image. How can I do this on Android?

Can anyone lead me?

Comment: Do you mean display a 3D images on a 3D handset like the EVO3D or just take an image and display it onto a 3D OpenGL canvas?

Comment: Without additional information? Impossible, what should the 3rd dimension be?

Comment: For my app I have some images with a person and when I display them on screen it must looks like 3D