# Android Canvas View the shape (Drawing by finger) in 3D View

Tags: android, canvas

I am using a Canvas to draw shapes or path using finger and implementing various operations on the drawing path or images like Clear, Undo, Redo, Fill, Thickness.

I am successfully doing all that but what I need after drawing the path or shapes user can view it in 3D view. I mean when user clicks on 3D button the view changes to 3D and the user can see after scrolling it. I don’t have the idea about 3D view of images using Canvas.

If there are any solutions to do this would be great to hear them.

[image]

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.drawactivity);
    drawView = new DrawView(DrawActivity.this);
    FrameLayout frm_layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    frm_layout.addView(drawView);
}

public void colorChanged(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
}

public void onButtonClick(View view) {

    int view_id = view.getId();

    switch (view_id) {

    case R.id.undo:
        isToBeEdited = true;
        drawView.onClickUndo();
        break;
    case R.id.redo:
        isToBeEdited = true;
        drawView.onClickRedo();
        break;
    case R.id.ClearPaint:
        isToBeEdited = true;
        undonePaths.clear();
        paths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        drawView.invalidate();
        break;
    case R.id.Upload:
        isToBeEdited = true;
        Intent i = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        );
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        break;
    case R.id.Fill:
        isToBeEdited = false;
        if (Fill) {
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            Fill = false;

        } else {
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            Fill = true;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.Thikness:
        if (thick) {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(15);
            thick = false;
            //drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        } else {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
            thick = true;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.ThreeD:
        isToBeEdited = false;
        if (shad) {
            mPaint.setShadowLayer(5, 4, 12, Color.BLACK);
            mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgreen));
            shad = false;
        } else {
            mPaint.clearShadowLayer();
            mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            shad = true;
        }
        break;
    case R.id.Rotate:
        Log.d("mvc", "m in Rotate");
        mCanvas.rotate(180, mCanvas.getWidth() / 2, mCanvas.getHeight() / 2);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(7);

        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        // mCanvas.rotate(320, 166, 678);
        // mCanvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        // mCanvas.restore();
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        for (Path p : paths) {
            Log.d("mvc", "m in onDraw");
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        Log.d("mvc", "m in touchStart");
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        Log.d("mvc", "m in touch_move");
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        Log.d("mvc", "m in touch_up");
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath = new Path();
        paths.add(mPath);
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {
            Log.i("undo", "Undo elsecondition");
        }
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {
            Log.i("undo", "Redo elsecondition");
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794261/how-can-i-convert-a-2d-image-to-3d-on-android) ..same question..but no answer :P